# How to Pass Values Between Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I am doing Airline Reservation System using GUI with ASP.NET in C#. 
What I want is assign seats for user, after a user assign that seats, that seat cannot be assigned by others again. I try to use increment do this but instead of 1+1 = 2(that means seat number 2 is the next to be assigned), the system gives me 1+1=11. How can I do what I want?

I have 5 interfaces for this, and I need this assigned value stored in whole running process.
This is my code for the reservation button, I have 2 for it, First Class and Economy Class. Only 5 seats for First Class and 15 seats for Economy Class.
How can I do ?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["seats"] = "First Class";
    if (firstseatnum > 5)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the first class seats was fully booked. Can you change to economy class?");
        Response.Redirect("reservation.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ++firstseatnum;
        totalseatnum1 = Convert.ToInt32(firstseatnum+seatnum);
        Response.Redirect("~/information.aspx?firstseatnum="+firstseatnum+"&seatnum="+totalseatnum1);
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["seats"] = "Economy Class";
    if (economyseatnum > 20)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the economy class seats was fully booked. Can you change to first class?");
        Response.Redirect("reservation.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ++economyseatnum;
        totalseatnum2 = Convert.ToInt32(economyseatnum + seatnum);
        Response.Redirect("information.aspx?economyseatnum=" + economyseatnum + "&seatnum="+totalseatnum2);
    }
}
```

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `seatnum` is a string.

If so, try

```
totalseatnum1 = firstseatnum + Convert.ToInt32(seatnum);
```

and

```
totalseatnum2 = economyseatnum + Convert.ToInt32(seatnum);
```

Comment: when i run to that page, error message: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: If it possible that seatnum is null or empty to begin with?

Comment: If so, try `totalseatnum1 = firstseatnum + (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seatnum) ? Convert.ToInt32(seatnum) : 0)`

Comment: i didn't initialize seatnum, okay i will try this! Thank you!

Comment: It worked thank you !!!! But now I have another problem, because the first class cannot be exceed 5 seats, so I have to set if (seatnum > 5) then pop up message box. However, the seatnum is string, how can I do this ?

Comment: Use the code above to convert `seatnum` to an `int`. Either initialize `seatnum` or use `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seatnum) ? Convert.ToInt32(seatnum) : 0`

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it:

**Query**

```
// Set
var myVariable = "MyData";
Response.Redirect("/NextPage?MyVariable=" + myVariable);

// Get
var data = Request.QueryString["MyVariable"];
```

**Cookie**

```
// Set
var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyVariable");
cookie.Value = "NyData";
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.Redirect("/NextPage");

// Get
var data = Request.Cookies["MyVariable"].Value;
```

**Session**

```
// Set
Session["MyVariable"] = "MyData";
Response.Redirect("/NextPage");

// Get
var data = Session["MyVariable"];
```

**Application (Store Entire Process)**

```
// Set
Application["MyVariable"] = "MyData";
Response.Redirect("/NextPage");

// Get
var data = Application["MyVariable"];
```

Also check [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8055/Transferring-page-values-to-another-page) to see more examples and detailed explanation.

Comment: We have not yet learn anything like this in the class I think, may I know how to achieve it with Session ? I have used that in my code to pass some values. Thank you.

Comment: @SilverArcher I'm adding code snippets, wait for it :)

Comment: Yes I have used Session method before, after first user input, the seat number 1 should be assigned so the second user should be assigned in seat number 2. But it gives me seat number 1 again.

Comment: @SilverArcher Store in `Application` then? It's global (process) storage.